# Android Multiple Spinner Updates

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Okay, so I'm working on an android app. In one of my app's activities (called convert), there are already 3 blank spinners (We'll ignore the third one for now). One main spinner lets the user decide on a topic such as temperature, pressure, or volume.

```
public class Convert extends Activity{
    String category = MySingleton.getInstance().getCategory();
    protected DataStorage appState;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.convert);

        appState = (DataStorage)getApplication();

        // Category Info
        Spinner convertTopic = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.convertTopic);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.convertTopic_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        convertTopic.setAdapter(adapter);

        category = MySingleton.getInstance().getCategory();
        // Subcategory Info
        Spinner inputUnit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.inputUnit);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2;
        adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.blank_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        if(category.equals("Temperature"))
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.convertUnitTemperature_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        else if(category.equals("Pressure"))
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.convertUnitPressure_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        else if(category.equals("Volume"))
            adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.convertUnitVolume_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        inputUnit.setAdapter(adapter2);

        convertTopic.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTopicSelectedListener());
    }
}
```

I also have a separate class that handles my first spinner selection.

```
public class OnTopicSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    String category = MySingleton.getInstance().getCategory();
    protected DataStorage appState;

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().length() != 0){
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Working with " +
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       category = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
       MySingleton.getInstance().setCategory(category);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

My issue is rather simple but I haven't found a solution to it.
Whenever that activity starts, everything is blank as expected. However, whenever someone selects an option from the main spinner *convertTopic*, the second spinner won't update.

The only way I can get the second spinner to update is to return to the previous activity and go back to the Convert activity. The main spinner will appear blank again but the second spinner is updated.

I want to make it so the second spinner updates the selection as soon as the user selects something from the main spinner. Is there any method I could use do this? Are there any loops involved?

I apologize if my question isn't clear. This is my first time asking a question on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the `OnItemSelectedListener` a separate class, make it an inner class of `Convert`. Then make your spinner variables members of `Convert` instead of just local variables within `onCreate`. Now your inner class will have direct access to the second spinner thus allowing you to manipulate it from within the `onItemSelected` method.

For a non-android explanation of inner class you can refer to the Java Tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea of inner classes.
Do I also declare the adapter objects outside the onCreate method? The app just crashes now.

Comment: Right. All the things you need to be able to access from the listener you should declare as members of the Activity. You should just use onCreate to initialize and set them up.

Comment: Okay so now I can manipulate the spinners from the inner class. However, I can't seem to update the data using that. 

I've tried 
adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.convertUnitVolume_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
from the onItemSelected method but it won't let me.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location TypeThe method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (Convert.OnTopicSelectedListener, int, int)

Comment: Nevermind, thank you. I wasn't thinking enough. All I needed to do was create three other adapters prior to this and then user the .setAdapter(adapter3) method.